# show varbinary image sql server in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to display an image stored in varbinary on sql server
And I have converted it so that it can be seen
Still does not show me anything
I share the code and hope they can help me

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "sa";
$userPassword = "";
$dbName = "Shop";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$userName, "PWD"=>$userPassword, "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$sql = "SELECT Imagen FROM Acessorios";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($result['Imagen'])  . '" >';
    echo "<br/>";

}


sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: Are you certain the format of the image is JPG?

Comment: Also I cannot find `image/jpg` in any reference as a valid MIME type. Have you tried `image/jpeg` ?

Comment: I change it by image/jpeg
Still does not show me anything

Comment: Have you tried limiting how much data you're getting back? I'm not sure how PHP handles things, if there are a lot of images in the database maybe it is taking awhile to pull everything? Try something like `SELECT TOP 1 Imagen FROM Acessorios`